# Will the old-style Facebook groups be converted to new-style Facebook groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

If they will be converted, has Facebook given any indication of its migration plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all new groups have notifications set on as default, I think there are still monitoring the load.

From [Facebook Help](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=18786) New Groups Design

> Currently you cannot convert an old group into the new group design.

You can read more on their blog.
[New Groups: Stay Closer to Groups of People in Your Life](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=434700832130)